# RemoteCertificateValidationCallback isn't working

Tags: c#, .net, httpclient

I'd like to disable remote SSL validation on a `SocketsHttpHandler` and I have written the following configuration:

```
socketsHttpHandler.SslOptions = new SslClientAuthenticationOptions
{
    RemoteCertificateValidationCallback = (a, b, c, d) =>
    {
        return true;
    }
};
httpClient = new HttpClient(socketsHttpHandler, false);
```

However, this isn't working in such a way that when I add a breakpoint to the `return true` line the code execution doesn't reach there meaning it is never invoked. I also tried ignoring the SSL globally:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (a, b, c, d) => {
    return true; 
};
```

and it also didn't work.

The error message I receive is:
The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.

Comment: Which version of .NET are you on?

Comment: @ThomasArdal: dotnet 6, but I already found the problem. I was copying headers from another request and there was a Host header set. I was causing the error after removing the host header, the problem was solved.

Comment: I see. Maybe write up an answer to your own question and mark it as correct for future visitors? I could totally have missed this too.

Comment: @ThomasArdal: sure, I will